# Consolidated updates in email (Daily or Weekly) for SharePoint Online site changes

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, notifications, newsletter

I have a requirement to setup custom notifications (weekly newsletter or updates of sites which user follow or has access) in SharePoint Online.

For example - There are 17K+ users in my current tenant and each user might be following some sites and has access to around 100+ sites. So, Users are expecting a consolidated summary report (weekly updates or newsletter) with the details of changes every week in his/her email.

- Weekly Updates/Newsletter from Sites/List/Library/Content- Which user is following
- Weekly Updates/Newsletter of Sites/List/Library/Content- Where user has access
- Weekly Updates/Newsletter of Sites/List/Library/Content - Which user has 
  added/Updated in this week

Could you please let me know if anyone has come across this requirement and if ***any OOTB solutions*** are available to handle this.

*Note: **Alert Me** option is not helpful in this case as it'll send updates of each list, we need consolidated weekly summary in a single email.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB functionality that meets your requirements.